# How To Fix My Time Waiting Method

Tags: java

My method `waitOut(seconds)` is developed to wait a certain amount of time till it passes to the next line of code that it was wedged between.

For example:

> System.out.println("I am going to eat a cheeseburger");
>
> waitOut(10); //<- 10 Seconds, that was converted in the method)
>
> System.out.println("I took a bite of that cheeseburger");

Here's the class

```
package Time;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/*
 * Developed for time passing of the game itself, doens't afflict with universal time
 */
 public class Timelapse {

     private static int timeInSeconds=0;
     private int timeInMinutes=0;
     private boolean day = true, night = false;
     private static Timer ourClock;
     private static TimerTask ourTask;

     public static void waitOut(int seconds) { // Method created for the time behind message print outs
        int num = seconds * 1000;
        ourClock = new Timer();
        ourTask = new Task();
        ourClock.scheduleAtFixedRate(ourTask,1000,1000);
    }   
}
```

Comment: so what is wrong?  what do you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: why not simply `Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);`?